# Replacing string value in 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to replace a string value in a 2d array and tried this codes below but nothing is happening

```
foreach (string item in Arr)
{
    if (UserInput.Equals(item))
    {
        item.Replace(UserInput, "X ");
    }
}
```

and the same goes for this codes nothing is happening...

```
Console.WriteLine("Select a seat that you want to ocupy");
string ln = Console.ReadLine();

if (ln.Equals(Arr))
{
    ln = ln.Replace(ln, "X ");
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that defines `Arr`.  Is it a `string[][]` or a `string[,]`?

Comment: ln.Equals(Arr) Compares a string with an array and will always return false

Comment: here's the code                                                              `string[,] Arr = new string[4,5]`
 {
     {"A1" , " A2" , " A3" , " A4" , " A5"},
     {"B1" , " B2" , " B3" , " B4" , " B5"},
     {"C1" , " C2" , " C3" , " C4" , " C5"},
     {"D1" , " D2" , " D3" , " D4" , " D5"},
    
 };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code

```
  item.Replace(UserInput, "X ");
```

creates *new* `String` which you then *ignore*; it could have been something like

```
  item = item.Replace(UserInput, "X ");
```

However, that's *impossible* within *foreach* loop, so let's try *for* loops:

```
  String[,] Arr = new String[,] {
    {"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"},
    {"B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"}
  };

  String UserInput = "B3";

  for(int line = Arr.GetLowerBound(0); line <= Arr.GetUpperBound(0); ++line)
    for(int column = Arr.GetLowerBound(1); column <= Arr.GetUpperBound(1); ++column)
      if (Arr[line, column].Contains(UserInput)) 
        Arr[line, column] = "X";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
   string ln = Console.ReadLine();
   for (int i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
        Arr[i] = Arr[i].Replace(ln, "X ");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ln.Equals(Arr))
{
    ln = ln.Replace(ln, "X ");
}
```

What is Arr ? is it Array Object?

If it yes, You can't just make equals with the whole array

you need to check each of it by using for loop or something

```
for (int i=0, len = Arr.Length; i < len; i++ )
{
    if (ln.Equals(Arr[i]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("old ln = " + ln);
        ln = ln.Replace(ln, "X ");
        Console.WriteLine("new ln = " + ln);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string[,] Arr = new string[4, 5];
        string textToReplace = "test";
        for(int k=0;k < Arr.GetLength(0);k++)
         for(int l=0;l < Arr.GetLength(1);l++)
             if (Arr[k,l]==textToReplace){
                 Arr[k, l] = "X";
             }
```